# How can I pass a value with a $ to a program run through su?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to run one of the script as below:

> su - oracle -c 'cd /tmp/somepath; sh -x myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
>   obj$_jghd$:jhdbcdj:hshabsh'

where arg4(obj$_jghd$:jhdbcdj:hshabsh) should be treated as one argument and calling in for loop in myscript.sh
Below is the sample code

```
id1=$1
id2=$2
id3=$3
name=$4
S_Object=`echo ""${name}""|sed 's/:/ /g'`
```

here I am reformating agr4 and removing the delimiter : with space and trying to nullify $. But when running the script all variables are not getting stored which contains $ and getting this error:

```
+ name='obj$:jhdbcdj:hshabsh'
++ echo 'obj$:jhdbcdj:hshabsh'
++ sed 's/:/ /g'
++ sed '/s/$/$/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `$'
```

Can you please help to get the right string stored in **name** variable.

I want the result should be like :

```
echo $S_Object

S_Object='obj$_jghd$ jhdbcdj hshabsh'
```

but I am getting as below :

```
echo $S_Object
S_Object='obj$ jhdbcdj hshabsh'
```

Comment: If you want to escape a value to be safe to parse as code, use `printf %q` to do that automatically; don't try to do it yourself with `sed`.

Comment: Can you please be specific about how `id1`, `id2`, `id3`, etc. are supposed to be combined into `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` and your final string? (Is it a fixed constant? What *is* it?)

Comment: *Why* are you trying to remove the `:`s in arg4? We see that in your code, but I don't see any textual description of the intent.

Comment: BTW, to understand *why* you shouldn't be adding "escaping" to literal strings, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050); the same misunderstandings that lead to the practices that FAQ discusses are the ones that lead to trying to put escape characters (which are syntax) into string variables' contents (which are data).

Comment: Unfortunately, *the way your script is being run* is destroying information before the script is even started, because the shell that `su` is invoking is replacing `$_jghd` with an empty string (since there's no variable by that name).

Comment: BTW, you're tagging this `bash`, but using `sh`. They're two different shells -- if the use of `sh` is deliberate, I'd suggest changing the tag. (`sh` doesn't guarantee any features not described in the POSIX sh specification; even if your operating system uses a copy of `sh` provided by bash, it turns off some functionality when invoked under that name).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you'll need to fix the code that's starting your script -- the `name` variable is already corrupt before the script starts, because the shell that `su` invokes is replacing `$_jghd` with an empty string before the explicit `sh -x` script is invoked.

To generate code containing data, use `printf %q`, as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
value='obj$_jghd$:jhdbcdj:hshabsh'
printf -v cmd '%q ' sh -x myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 "$value"
su - oracle -c "cd /tmp/somepath && $cmd"
```

Note the use of bash, *not* `sh`, as `printf %q` isn't present in POSIX-baseline shells, and further isn't guaranteed to generate POSIX-compliant output. (Consequently, for this to be reliable with all possible values, the `oracle` user should be configured with `bash` as its shell).

---

Alternately, you can pass values through the environment:

```
#!/bin/sh
value='obj$_jghd$:jhdbcdj:hshabsh'
value="$value" su - oracle -c 'cd /tmp/somepath && ./myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 "$value"'
```

Reassigning `value` on the same line as `su` puts it in `su`'s environment, which is then inherited by the shell later expanding `$value`.

Comment: actually su - oracle -c will be added in the tool that I can not remove. so that it needs to run as su - oracle -c 'sh myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 "$value"'
I have tried "$value" but that also did not work.

Comment: Report a bug to that other tool's authors. What they're doing is not just treating data nonliterally, it's also a security concern since it's evaluating data as if it were code.

Comment: su - oracle -c 'sh myscript.sh "obj$_jghd$:jhdbcdj:hshabsh"'
obj$ jhdbcdj hshabsh

so Still above output I am getting but it should be

obj$_jghd$ jhdbcdj hshabsh

Comment: If your outer shell is bash, you can use `su - oracle -c $'sh Gather_Stats.sh \'obj$_jghd$:jhdbcdj:hshabsh\''` That won't work if run from `sh`, though.

Comment: The important thing about the above is that it's using single quotes around the literal value with the `$`s. You can use double quotes around a *parameter expansion* that expands to that value, but you can't use them around the literal value itself.

Comment: I can not add $ just after su - oracle -c . if I add it after going into tool it will run as su - oracle -c '$sh myscript.sh ....

Comment: `$'...'` is an [alternate quoting form for bash](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings). It's syntax, not something you can put in your data. (Frankly, it feels to me like confusing the difference between syntax and data is half the cause of this question. Using `su` causes an `eval` pass when the shell it invokes parses the script it's passed, so the line between syntax and data *does* get blurred at that point -- but one needs to understand that that's an exception, not the rule, to think straight about what's going on at execution time).

Comment: Anyhow, **exactly** how is the tool you can't change invoking `su`? The precise details matter, if we're going to be munging your data into a form that the shell `su` invokes will interpret correctly. It may well be that it can't be fixed, but we can't know either way until we see the implementation with no simplifications or changes.

Comment: (or, rather, until we see a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code that *reproduces the exact problem* and describes which parts can and cannot be changed as part of a proposed fix; if a question doesn't let folks trying to answer it know what they are and aren't allowed to change, how can anyone build a solid answer?)

Comment: ...but anyhow, you should use `$'...'` *when passing data to the script you can't change from the parent script you can change*. If you run `./myprogram $'foo\nbar'`, the `$` isn't part of the data `myprogram` receives -- it's just the syntax that *your shell* parsed to understand that it should pass `myprogram` an argument that consists of the word `foo`, then a newline literal, then the word `bar`; the dollar sign and the quotes are removed by that parent shell after it uses them to inform how it should do the parsing. (Even the backslash isn't passed to `myprogram` either!).

Comment: The other important reason to use `builtin printenv` is that the `-v` option is impossible in the external command.  On my Linux system, `/usr/bin/printf` generates more portable output, but obviously needs to be in a command substitution if we're to assign to `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the syntax errors and outdated idioms in your script.

This seems to work :

```
#!/bin/bash

id1=$1
id2=$2
id3=$3
name=$4
S_Object=$( echo "${name}" | sed 's/:/ /g' | sed 's/$/\$/g'  )

echo "$S_Object"
```

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: It didn't help much.
S_Object='obj$ jhdbcdj hshabsh'

Comment: I have removed sed 's/$/\$/g' seems $ escaping is not needed

Comment: still, full string is not coming after $ sign

Comment: You aren't explaining what *should* come after the `$`, so how is anyone but you supposed to know whether an answer is correct?

Comment: with myscript.sh I have passed obj$_jghd$ then other string with : saperated. But getting obj$ so _jghd$ is getting ignored after first $

Answer (score 0):

Change the second sed command to `sed 's/$ /$_/g'`
then you should get your desired output.